# How to delete messages EFFICIENTLY with Discord bot

Tags: node.js, performance, discord, discord.js, bots

I want have a Discord Music Bot that when it leaves the voice channel it clears the text channel from commands and logs. But the problem is that it takes too much time (up to 1-3 mins). I have seen other that other bots are able to do the same in much lower time, so how can I make my code better?

Here is my code, that it does work, but I would like to make the bot delete messages faster:

```
} else if (msg.content.trim().toLowerCase() == _CMD_LEAVE) {
        const channel = msg.channel;
        const messageManager = channel.messages;
        messageManager.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then((messages) => {
             messages.forEach((message) => {
                 if ((message.author.id == 0123456789) || (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))) {  
                     message.delete();
                 }  
             });
        });
        
        if (guildMap.has(mapKey)) {
            
            let val = guildMap.get(mapKey);
            if (val.voice_Channel) val.voice_Channel.leave()
            if (val.voice_Connection) val.voice_Connection.disconnect()
            if (val.musicYTStream) val.musicYTStream.destroy()
                guildMap.delete(mapKey)
            msg.reply("Disconnected.")    

        } else {
            msg.reply("Cannot leave because not connected.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What language is this written in and what Discord framework are you using?

Comment: Im using node.js and discord.js

Comment: The issue here is you'll hit rate limits, we cannot delete messages "fast" anymore. You have to make a queue of the items you want removed and slowly destroy the messages to not get blocked.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK i have been reading a bit, isn't bulkDelete() an option now? I was thinking on something like  creating a messages object(i really dont know how to) stacking there the messages and then bulkDelete() that object? Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes you can, it's well documented here. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete You can use a collection (snowflake message or array) or number of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js has a feature to prune a large number of messages.

First, you fetch all messages in the channel up to a certain point (e.g. the latest 100 messages), then filter them depending on your criteria.
Afterwards, you use `channel.bulkDelete(messages)` to immediately delete all of them.
This only works for messages younger than 14 days sadly, but it's much more efficient than manually deleting them.
The code could look somewhat like this:

```js
//fetch 100 most recent messages
channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100}).then(messages => {
    //filter the messages to only delete messages by a certain user
    messages = messages.filter(m => m.author.id === useridhere)

    //bulk delete the messages
    channel.bulkDelete(messages)

})
```

Comment: could I add another filter this way? `messages = messages.filter(m => (m.author.id === useridhere) || (m.content.startsWith(PREFIX)))` or should I delete in 2 groups?

Comment: Yes, that works!
In that case, it would prune any messages by a specific user or any messages that start with a specific prefix!